# How to Save line/polygon location data as csv for later import

Tags: qgis

I have some Line layers that I would like to save as as a `.csv` file, edit the attibute columns and the re-import to be saved as a shapefile.

How can I add geometry or location attributes to be saved as `.csv`, and how do I correctly manage them when importing? Would also be interested to know if this can be done for Polygons.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for exporting the layer into a `.csv` file ? A lot of modifications (data and column names) can be done directly under QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Save your layer as csv and in layer options, set GEOMETRY as WKT. Then you will get some "magical" text strings that defines your geometries as the first field (look up WKT, "Well known text" for a closer explanation). This should work both for lines and polygons (I have only tried with lines), although you may get into issues with too long lines if you have complicated geometries.

One thing more, depending on the software you are using to handle the csv file, You may want to use another Field separator than comma, since the commas are used - hardcoded - within the strings defining your geometry. You may get strings quoted, which may work or not work depending on your parser.

If you want to read it into an excel installation which is set up with comma as field separator, you will find your file gets total mangeled, since excel will split the geometry in the WKT-fields.

In this case: Set tab as field separator. Save the file. Rename it from .csv to .dat. Open the file in excel, it will ask you for the field separator, tell it to use tab.

As said above, complicated geometries will give you very long lines that may cause problems. A lot of editing can be done in QGIS, if you go into the field calculator, you will even be able to write python scripts to update your fields.

Comment: You just saved me from a 3-hour long frustration over this issue. Merely saying: **"Just save the layer as `csv` and specify `AS_WKT` in the GEOMETRY field"** was not working for me and I had started to think my QGIS installation has issues. 
I didn't know that the issue was `Excel` which, as always, tries to be smarter that it actually is (thinking about how dealing with dates strings in the software is a nightmare).